# Appending to string each time a substring is found

Tags: php, string, substring

I have a string that is made of html `srcset`. I extracted the value of `srcset` using DOMDocument, it's something like:

```
$srcset = "/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/something-970x647-c-300x190.jpg 300w, 
/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/something-970x647-c-120x76.jpg 120w, 
/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/something-970x647-c-265x168.jpg 265w";
```

As you can see, urls are relative. I want to change them into absolute form with the host being something like `http://example.com`

For that I was thinking of looping through occurrences of `/wp-content` in the string and append the host url to its beginning.

How do I do that?

Comment: Use [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to get an array where each url is an array element. Then you can conveniently append something to each element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$srcset = str_replace('/wp-content/', 'http://example.com/wp-content/', $srcset);
```

Comment: WOW. how did I not know this? No need to loop or anything.